# Is there a way to extract time from datetime objects in Python?

Tags: python

I want to extract time values from a datetime object in Python. This is the code I used:

```
t = '2018-12-16 17:59:00'
t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

There is clearly something wrong with the code because I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I am using Python 3 and I need to convert around 30000 datetime values.

Comment: That is basically because you are using a string and not a `datetime` object. And BTW you are extracting the time, not the date as written in the headline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
t = '2018-12-16 17:59:00'
t = dt.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(t.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

in datetime methods

strptime is the mehtod to convert from string to datetime

strftime is the method to convert from datetime to string

Answer (score 0):

That's a string, not a datetime object. You should probably be using a datetime object:

```
t = datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
```

But if you want to use your string, you can splice it into two (space-separated) parts:

```
t = t.split()  # t = ['2018-12-16', '17:59:00']
```

Then take the first part:

```
date = t[0]
```